# Getting ERROR CODE:PE106 in 2Checkout Payment api?

Tags: api, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am trying to use 2checkout for an online payment project but gives ERROR CODE:PE106 when I try to go for a payment(Image attached).
[2checkout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RleGq.png)

Comment: did u solve it, if yes what is the solution

Comment: @ZOthix Yes, the account was not approved that's why it was showing ERROR CODE: PE106